# Is there an equivalent of the "blocktrans" in tag in jinja2?

Tags: python, django, porting, gettext, jinja2

I am using jinja2 with my django application, I am working on porting some existing django templates over to jinja2. For the most part I am not having any issues; however, I have a statement like so in one of my django templates:

```
{% blocktrans %}
  <p>Some stuff here</p>
{% endblocktrans %}
```

This causes jinja2 to become very unhappy. I have looked far and wide to see if there is an equivalent of the "blocktrans" tag for jinja2. All I can find is that enabling gettext let's you use:

```
{{ trans("Some String") }}
```

This is useful for short strings like in the title tag, but not for blocks. What am I missing, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `{% trans %}` and its complement `{% endtrans %}` once the [`i18n`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#i18n-in-templates) extension is enabled.

Comment: But `trans` can-not replace `blocktrans` ? They have there specific purposes !